# 3 reputation for an upvote on an answer?

Tags: support, reputation

So my answer to the question [How can i effectively solo the co-op mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53633/how-can-i-effectively-solo-the-co-op-mode/55780#55780) got its third upvote and in my reputation log it says i gained 3 rep points.[image: +3 reputation]

i did notice some talk about a reputation cap didnt think it would be in the 200s range. Maybe im just not experienced enough and missed something in the FAQ somewhere.

i marked it as bug cause i didnt know what else to put it as.

Comment: @bwarner thanks!

Comment: now all you have to do is reach this cap every day for the next half a year and you'll have a shot to catch up to @Agent86 :P

Comment: @yx haha yay...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit the daily reputation cap of 200 from upvotes and suggested edits. Specifically, you made [one suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/3819) worth +2 early in the day. So, the other votes eventually gave you 195, totalling 197 reputation by the time you got that vote. That makes the vote only able to give you +3 (and further votes worth no more for the day).

Comment: what about bounties?

Comment: Bounties and accepts are not affected in any way by the reputation cap, and vice versa. You also got no bounties today, so it had no chance of impacting you getting +3 today. ♪

Answer (score 1):

There is a daily reputation cap of 200 which you hit today, so you can't earn any more reputation from upvotes today. Reputation for accepting answers and getting answers accepted is exempt from the cap, that's why you got 208 reputation.

Comment: what about bounties?